# How can I install zipline using conda with python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, zipline

I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.5

My end goal is to install the `zipline` python package and get it to run properly. However, I have hit some obstacles and since I am new to Unix and python as well, I thought maybe someone could push me in the right direction.

On the [zipline website](http://www.zipline.io/) it says there is support for `python 3.5`. I already have `python 3.6` installed via `conda` on my system so I decided to create an environment for the former version.

First, I did `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda` in the directory `/anaconda/envs/py35`. This installed `python 3.5.3`. Then, I use `source activate py35` to activate it.

Next, I attempt to install `zipline` using a suggestion on their website with the command:

```
conda install -c Quantopian zipline
```

And I receive this error back:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in 
conflict:
  - python 3.5*
  - zipline -> logbook -> python 2.7*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I'm not sure I fully understand why `python 2.7` would be in conflict if I am working from within an environment, I assumed that was the point, so nothing conflicts with other python versions. Also, it says `python 3.5*` does that mean it's in conflict with itself? Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you give `pip install zipline` a try. A lot of times `conda` doesn't work for me, whereas `pip` does.

Comment: @VikashSingh Yes, I am trying it now, `pip` did install zipline but when I attempt to run a script I get an error `No module named pandas.tseries.tools`

Comment: I Don't know what `buyaapl.py` is. Please share the code in a separate question. Thanks. Probably you don't have pandas installed in the environment. Try `pip install pandas`

Comment: @VikashSingh Apologies, it is the script seen in [this zipline tutorial](http://www.zipline.io/beginner-tutorial.html), when I type `conda list` it gives me two versions of `pandas`. One is `py35_0` and one is `<pip>` (which I installed within my environment, I think).

Comment: Did you try to create an environment without installing anaconda? I mean `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 -c Quantopian zipline`. I hope this should work as per this discussion https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/1797#issuecomment-315592153.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comment:

```
pip install zipline
```

> did you give pip install zipline a try. A lot of times conda doesn't work for me, whereas pip does.

--

> @VikashSingh Yes, I am trying it now, pip did install zipline but when I attempt to run a buyaapl.py script I get an error No module named pandas.tseries.tools

I have no clue what `buyaapl.py` is. Please start another question and share the code as well.

PS: Probably you don't have pandas installed in the environment. Try `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Answer (score -1):

You should run the `conda install -c Quantopian zipline` after you activated your conda environment. 
`source activate py35`

Then, when you see your shell becomes `(py35)$`, you can run `conda install -c Quantopian zipline` again.

ref: http://www.zipline.io/install.html